# How to send multiple jQuery datepicker values to a database

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, datepicker

I am creating a website that facilitates setting a meeting time for a group of people, very much like [WhenIsGood](http://whenisgood.net/).

When creating a new meeting, users start by inputting the dates that a meeting could possibly occur (using a jQuery datepicker with form inputs).  The form starts with three fields, but users can add more as needed.  My question is, how can I store the date values so that they can be used later?  The values will be used again in the meeting creation process when users have to select a time range for each submitted date value.  Also, the final tentative schedule (days submitted and time ranges submitted) will need to be made available to group members.  I know, this is pretty abstract at the moment, and I'll be more than happy to give more details if necessary.  [Here is the page in question](http://itcs4155.vacau.com/createmeeting.php).

My main concern is figuring out how to store the values without knowing how many values there will be.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.  I have a SQL database that I have set up and am using.  I assume the data would be stored there since, you know, it's a database.  Or if there's a better way, that's cool too.  Thanks in advance.

```
<?php 
include 'core/init.php';
//protect_page();
include 'includes/overall/header.php'; 
?>    

      <form action="sendemail.php" method="post">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
           $(document).ready(function() {
                var count = 4;
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: '+0D', numberOfMonths: 2});
                $( 'input[type="text"]' ).datepicker();

                $("#addDate").click(function(){
                     $('#dateholder').append('<p>Date: <input id="dp' + count + '" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>');
                     count++;
                     $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: '+0D', numberOfMonths: 2});
                     $( 'input[type="text"]' ).datepicker();
                });
           });               
      </script>

      <h1>Create a Meeting</h1>
      <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20%;">
      <div id="dateholder" style="text-align:center;">
           <p>Date: <input id="dp1" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
           <p>Date: <input id="dp2" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
           <p>Date: <input id="dp3" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
      </div>
      <div style="text-align:center;">
           <p><input type="button" value="Add Date" id="addDate" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit Dates"/></p>
      </div>
      </div>
      </form>

<?php include 'includes/overall/footer.php'; ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can replace

```
<p>Date: <input id="dp1" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
<p>Date: <input id="dp2" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
<p>Date: <input id="dp3" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
```

with

```
<p>Date: <input name="dp[]" type="text" class="datepicker" /></p>
```

After you can read in PHP page:

```
<?php 
   for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['dp']); $i++){
       echo $_POST['dp'][$i]."<br/>";        
   }

 ?>
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, and thanks for the help.  This works if I use name="dp[]" rather than id="dp[]."  Looking at it now, it seems really obvious.  Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use array notation for the dtepicker names:

```
<input name="dp[]" type="text" class="datepicker" />
```

Then in PHP you can access `$_POST['dp']` as an array.